# Plupload retry if error

Tags: javascript, plupload

I'm trying to setup plupload so that if a file upload fails according to a certain error code, plupload will try to upload it again. Without success.

**What I currently have**

Here is my piece of code for now :

```
var attempts = 0; // number of attempts

function init(uploader) {

    uploader.bind('Error', function(up, file) {

        var code = JSON.parse(file.response).error.code;
        console.log(code); //logs the error code

        if(code === 503 && attempts > 3) {


            up.stop();
            file.status = plupload.FAILED;
            file.retry = false;

            // do stuff...

            up.state = plupload.STARTED;
            up.trigger("StateChanged");
            attempts = 0;
        }
        else {

            console.log("attempt : "+ attempts);
            up.stop();
            file.status = plupload.QUEUED;
            attempts++;
            file.retry = true;

            up.state = plupload.STARTED;
            up.trigger("StateChanged");
            up.trigger("QueueChanged"); // ERROR HERE
        }
    })
}
```

Where I indicated the "ERROR HERE", my console shows me this :

> TypeError: n.getSource is not a function

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the file again on the queue?
http://www.plupload.com/docs/Uploader#addFile-filefileName-method

```
addFile(file, [fileName])
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that, but it's not trying, it simply doesnt increment. Any tips ?

Comment: Is it just part of your code? If yes, please update that with the rest of the code.